# How can I organize files based on their filename first letter into A-Z folders

Tags: command-line, files

I am looking for a way (preferably terminal) to organize over 1000 fonts by their first letter.

Basically create directories `A-Z, #` then move the font files to those directories based on their filename first character. Fonts that begin with numbers [0-9] or other special characters to be moved to the `#` directory.

Comment: Do you want the directories to be made even if there are no files starting with that letter?

Comment: @Arronical Nope. Just if there are files.

Comment: I hope this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251938/move-files-to-directories-based-on-first-part-of-filename

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A late python option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import shutil

def path(dr, f): return os.path.join(dr, f)

dr = sys.argv[1]
for f in os.listdir(dr):
    fsrc = path(dr, f)
    if os.path.isfile(fsrc):
        s = f[0]; target = path(dr, s.upper()) if s.isalpha() else path(dr, "#")
        if not os.path.exists(target):
            os.mkdir(target)
        shutil.move(fsrc, path(target, f))
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `move_files.py`
2. Run it with the directory as argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/move_files.py /path/to/files
   ```

The script will only create the (sub) directory(-ies) (uppercase) if it is actually needed

#### Explanation

The script:

- lists the files, gets the first character (defines the sourcepath):

  ```py
  for f in os.listdir(dr):
      s = f[0]; fsrc = path(dr, f)
  ```
- checks if the item is a file:

  ```py
  if os.path.isfile(fsrc):
  ```
- defines the targeted folder for either if the first char is alpha or not:

  ```py
  target = path(dr, s.upper()) if s.isalpha() else path(dr, "#")
  ```
- checks if the folder already exists or not, creates it if not:

  ```py
  if not os.path.exists(target):
      os.mkdir(target)
  ```
- moves the item into its corresponding folder:

  ```py
  shutil.move(fsrc, path(target, f))
  ```

Comment: Hey Jacob. Is there a check for uppercase first letters?

Comment: @Parto Absolutely! In what way do you need it? (I can check in 3,5 hrs teaching :)

Comment: It actually did. Perfect implementation.

Comment: After considering, I have decided to go with this answer for several reasons: 1). The explanation on what is going on. 2). The answer run correctly on first try

Answer (score 11):

Code-golfed yet readable with just two commands and two regular expressions:

```sh
mkdir -p '#' {a..z}
prename -n 's|^[[:alpha:]]|\l$&/$&|; s|^[0-9]|#/$&|' [[:alnum:]]?*
```

If you have a huge amount of files to move, too many to fit into the process argument list (yes, there's a limit and it may be just a few kilobytes), you can generate the file list with a different command and pipe that to `prename`, e. g.:

```sh
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '[[:alnum:]]?*' -printf '%f\n' |
prename -n 's|^[[:alpha:]]|\l$&/$&|; s|^[0-9]|#/$&|'
```

This has the added benefit of not trying to move the literal file name `[[:alnum:]]?*` if no files match the glob pattern. `find` also allows many more match criteria than shell globbing.
An alternative is to set the `nullglob` shell option and close the standard input stream of `prename`.<sup>1</sup>

In both cases remove the `-n` switch to actually move the files and not just show how they would be moved.

*Addendum:* You can remove the empty directories again with:

```sh
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '#' {a..z}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `shopt -s nullglob; prename ... <&-`

Answer (score 8):

I didn't work out a nice way to make the directory names uppercase (or move the files with uppercase letters), although you could do it afterwards with `rename`...

```sh
mkdir {a..z} \#; for i in {a..z}; do for f in "$i"*; do if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then echo mv -v -- "$f" "$i"; fi; done; done; for g in [![:alpha:]]*; do if [[ -f "$g" ]]; then echo mv -v -- "$g" \#; fi; done
```

or more readably:

```sh
mkdir {a..z} \#; 
for i in {a..z}; do 
  for f in "$i"*; do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then 
      echo mv -v -- "$f" "$i"; 
    fi 
  done
done
for g in [![:alpha:]]*; do 
  if [[ -f "$g" ]]; then 
    echo mv -v -- "$g" \#
  fi
done
```

Remove `echo` after testing to actually move the files

And then

```sh
rename -n 'y/[a-z]/[A-Z]/' *
```

remove `-n` if it looks good after testing and run again.

Comment: You can use `if [[ -d "${i^}" ]]` to make the variable `i` capital, and `mkdir {A..Z}` at the start.

Comment: Let me try this and see

Comment: @Arronical thanks! I will leave it however, since you posted it your own way

Comment: @Zanna I like that we came at it from different directions, iterating through the letters and using them as search criteria had never occurred to me. I'm sure there's a clever and fast solution with find, but can't get my head around it!

Comment: Hey Zanna, this didn't move the fonts that start with an uppercase letter. Otherwise worked fine.

Comment: @Parto Ah yeah that's a weakness of doing it this way, you'd have to run it again like `for i in {A..Z}; do for f in "$i"*; do if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then echo mv -v -- "$f" "$i"; fi; done; done` to catch the uppercase ones too

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind zsh, a function and a couple of `zmv` commands:

```
mmv() {echo mkdir -p "${2%/*}/"; echo mv -- "$1" "$2";}
autoload -U zmv
zmv -P mmv '([a-zA-Z])(*.ttf)' '${(UC)1}/$1$2'
zmv -P mmv '([!a-zA-Z])(*.ttf)' '#/$1$2'
```

The `mmv` function makes the directory and moves the file. `zmv` then  provides pattern-matching and substitution. First, moving filenames starting with an alphabet, then everything else:

```
$ zmv -P mmv '([a-zA-Z])(*.ttf)' '${(UC)1}/$1$2'
mkdir -p A/
mv -- abcd.ttf A/abcd.ttf
mkdir -p A/
mv -- ABCD.ttf A/ABCD.ttf
$ zmv -P mmv '([!a-zA-Z])(*.ttf)' '#/$1$2'
mkdir -p #/
mv -- 123.ttf #/123.ttf
mkdir -p #/
mv -- 七.ttf #/七.ttf
```

Run again without the `echo` in `mmv`'s definition to actually perform the move.

Answer (score 7):

The following commands within the directory containing the fonts should work, if you want to use from outside the font storage directory, change `for f in ./*` to `for f in /directory/containing/fonts/*`. This is a very shell based method, so quite slow, and is also non-recursive. This will only create directories, if there are files which start with the matching character.

```sh
target=/directory/to/store/alphabet/dirs
mkdir "$target"
for f in ./* ; do 
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then 
    i=${f##*/}
    i=${i:0:1}
    dir=${i^}
    if [[ $dir != [A-Z] ]]; then 
      mkdir -p "${target}/#" && mv "$f" "${target}/#"
    else
      mkdir -p "${target}/$dir" && mv "$f" "${target}/$dir"
    fi
  fi
done
```

As a one liner, again from within the font storage directory:

```sh
target=/directory/to/store/alphabet/dirs; mkdir "$target" && for f in ./* ; do if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then i=${f##*/}; i=${i:0:1} ; dir=${i^} ; if [[ $dir != [A-Z] ]]; then mkdir -p "${target}/#" && mv "$f" "${target}/#"; else mkdir -p "${target}/$dir" && mv "$f" "${target}/$dir" ; fi ; fi ; done
```

A method using find, with similar string manipulation, using bash parameter expansion, which will be recursive, and should be somewhat quicker than the pure shell version:

```sh
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'target=/directory/to/store/alphabet/dirs ; mkdir -p "$target"; f="{}" ; i="${f##*/}"; i="${i:0:1}"; i=${i^}; if [[ $i = [[:alpha:]] ]]; then mkdir -p "${target}/$i" && mv "$f" "${target}/$i"; else mkdir -p "${target}/#" && mv "$f" "${target}/#"; fi' \;
```

Or more readably:

```sh
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'target=/directory/to/store/alphabet/dirs 
   mkdir -p "$target"
   f="{}"
   i="${f##*/}"
   i="${i:0:1}"
   i=${i^}
   if [[ $i = [[:alpha:]] ]]; then 
      mkdir -p "${target}/$i" && mv "$f" "${target}/$i"
   else
      mkdir -p "${target}/#" && mv "$f" "${target}/#"
   fi' \;
```

Comment: This one worked too. Even for uppercase and lowercase letters.

Answer (score 5):

Map each filename to a directory name using `tr`, then `mkdir` and `mv`:

```sh
find /src/dir -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -I{} bash -c \
  'dir=/dest/$(basename "{}" | cut -c1 | tr -C "a-zA-Z\n" "#" | tr "a-z "A-Z"); mkdir -p $dir; mv "{}" $dir'
```

Comment: I really like this, this is along the lines of what I was grasping for with my wish to use find. Is there a way to only create upper case directory names, and move lower case filenames into them?

Comment: I added another `tr` to convert to uppercase.

Comment: Why the detour through `xargs` just to call `bash` again? Wouldn't it be simpler and much more readable to pipe the output of `find` into a while-loop and `read` it there record-by-record?

Comment: Good question, @DavidFoerster.  I guess bias against loops in one-liners and preference for a more functional approach.  But a bash script in a string isn't very elegant either, so I'd say the `while` loop version (http://bit.ly/2j2mhyb) is perhaps better.

Comment: By the way, you can avoid the nasty `{}` substitution if you let `xargs` append the argument and then refer to `$1` inside the shell script, e. g.: `xargs -0 -n1 -- bash -c 'dir=/dest/$(basename "$1" | ...); ...; mv "$1" "$dir"' _`. (Mind the final `_`!)